# Moving a whole line string to the right

Tags: c#, string

```
        const string Duom = "Text.txt";
        char[] seperators = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Duom, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

            string GLine = " " + lines[i];
            GLine = Regex.Replace(GLine, @"\s+", " ");
            GLine = GLine.PadRight(5, ' ');
            Console.WriteLine(GLine);
        }
```

Reads a text file, for each line it adds a whitespace at the start, removes all double and above whitespaces,  and I want to move the line to the right , but it doesn't do anything.

Result :
[image: Result of the program]

Expected Result:[image]

Comment: Did you mean PadLeft?  (You wrote PadRight)

Comment: The result is the same with both PadLeft and PadRight.

Comment: Do want each line to be 5 more spaces indented than the previous?

Comment: Pad will only do something if it's not that length already, That's why its padding ...

Comment: I understand how it works now, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PadLeft` and `PadRight` doesn't add characters to the start/end of your string if the specified length has already been reached.

From the [docs for String.PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.7.2) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by padding them on the right with a specified Unicode character, **for a specified total length**.

All of your strings are larger than `5`, the specified **total length**, so PadRight/PadLeft won't do anything.

"Padding" the string is adding spaces (or some other character) so that the new string is at least as large as the number you want.

Instead, just manually add 5 spaces before your string.

```
GLine = "     " + GLine;
```

Or more programmaticly:

```
GLine = new string(' ', 5) + GLine;
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted, it's a bit hard to understand the definitions of functions when english is my 3rd language.

Comment: If there's something I can clarify feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the body of your loop like this:

```
string GLine = new string(' ', 1 + i * 5) + Regex.Replace(lines[i], @"\s+", " ");
Console.WriteLine(GLine);
```

This will add 1 space and then 5 more spaces for each line.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            string GLine = new string(' ',5*i) + lines[i];

            Console.WriteLine(GLine);
        }
```

This should add 5 extra spaces for each line you have, which i believe is what you are trying to accomplish if i understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to left pad a tab depending on how many lines of text you have. The best increment to use is the i variable.

`string GLine = " " + lines[i];`
change this to
`string GLine = new String('\t', i) + lines[i];`

By the way, PadLeft should work but keep in mind you need to execute it i times